# CRUD PHP system "Not Acceptable!" Error when trying to create new mysql row

Tags: php, html

Here is my html form:

```
<form method='POST' action='/dss-assets/PHP/blog_editor.php' style='display: block;'>
 <input type='text' name='linker' placeholder='Link...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='cat' placeholder='Category...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='company_name' placeholder='Company Name...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='svg' placeholder='Svg...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='blog_title' placeholder='Blog Title...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='date_pub' placeholder='Date Published...'></input>
 <input type='text' name='blog_only' placeholder='Blog Only?'></input>
 <input type='submit' name='blog_add' value='Add Post.'></input>
</form>;
```

and here is the blog_editor.php file:

```
<?php
error_log(0);
if(isset($_POST['blog_add'])){
  $link = mysqli_connect(connection details);
  // Check connection
  if($link === false){
      die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $linker = $_POST['linker'];
  $category = $_POST['cat'];
  $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
  $svg = $_POST['svg'];
  $blog_title = $_POST['blog_title'];
  $date_pub = $_POST['date_pub'];
  $blog_only = $_POST['blog_only'];

  mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO blog_links (link, category, company_name, svg, blog_title, date_pub, blog_only) VALUES ('$linker', '$cat', '$company_name', '$svg', '$blog_title', '$date_pub', '$blog_only')");
  header('location: https://www.desertsunstudio.com/dss_blog_admin_links');
}

?>
```

however when i try to post a new link i get this error:

"Not Acceptable! An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."

and no PHP errors are logged. I am completely stumped any help would be greatly appreciated.
Oh also i tried adding this to my .htaccess but no avail.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @djalmafreestyler yes; you have to use a prepared statement using mysqli_prepare

Comment: @djalmafreestyler added solution to post

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a prepared statement to safely pass the information without errors

```
if (isset($_POST['blog_add'])) {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "databaseName");

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $category = $_POST['cat'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO blog_links (id, category) VALUES (?, ?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_0, $param_1);

    // Set parameters
    $param_0 = $id;
    $param_1 = $category;

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
    header("location: https://www.yoursite.com/blog_editor_path");
    exit();

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```